# Simple counter using AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

This is a simple counter using AsyncTask class:

```
   static private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer...prams) {
       while(t){
           i++;
           publishProgress(i);
           try {
               Thread.sleep(200);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Textview.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));  
    }
}
```

i is an Integer witch rising every 0.2 seconds and the value of it shows in Textview.So when i run my app the value of i show in textview and increase and update fast using asynctask class.
This is my question:
Why some times my Text view show a smaller value of i,for example afte 54 it shows 53 and then rising again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call
>   to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.

The timing of the update on your UI thread is not guaranteed so you could see the events come out of order like you describe.  You might want to add logic to your progress to just not decrease the value at all and only increase, basically skip the value if it is less than what you saw last time.

Comment: So we can say the time is not guaranteed but how it can show the previous value of the variable?!maybe it update take longer but it couldn't show the last value...

Comment: I think you should assume the order could be affected if the timing isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

There are main UI thread and other worker thread, to update Textview using AsyncTask, you should use [publishProgress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...))

The official help gives detailed explanation and sample, read it and try modify your codes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be implementing this via an AsyncTask.  All AsyncTasks share the same thread, sleeping on it will block any other task in the system.  This is acceptable only for very short tasks.  If your timer runs forever, no other async task in your app will ever work.  If you want a timer, use a handler or a thread, not an AsyncTask.

Comment: It's ok bro.but can you explain how i receive an smaller value of i variable?how it's occur?i must see equal or higher value cause there is no command for decrease it!